# When to fetch data from API via Vuex again to keep the data up to date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm fetching data from an API and want to achieve it via Vuex. So my users store module is holding and managing all users.

To fetch all users I have a `fetch` action which calls the API via Axios and passes the users array from the response to the mutation.

I have a view component at `/users` which renders a list of users. Within that component I call

```
async mounted() {
  await this.fetch();
}
```

to initialize the store. After that, the store getter will return the users array and the list gets rendered. I know that I can also fetch one item by id via getter

`getById: state => id => state.users.find(user => user.id === id)`

When navigating to a user detail page `/users/:id` I can make use of it, extract the userId via `this.$router.currentRoute.params.id` and render the user details. But what if I load that route directly? Then the store initialized with an empty users array and it won't find a single user.

So should I fetch all users again in the `mounted` hook of that user details view? I think calling the axios service directly would be an anti pattern because the resources say I should use Vuex as an interface between the component and the API.

Is there a best practise when to fetch all users from the api? Because let's image you navigate to another page which loads all users in a select component, should I fetch them from the getter? Maybe it will load a user that doesn't exist anymore. But polling all users every X seconds would be bad too...

What is the correct way to update the store data to make it accessible for all components in the entire application?

Comment: If `users` data is important for you in the entire application in real-time, you should directly fetch by polling( or maybe you can use a socket). If I were in that situation, I would use polling or socket. Because there isn't any other solution to get rid of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree that Vuex should be used to store an entire tables worth of user data in the manner you described. This sounds like a security concern to me. Remember that Vuex is a client-side store; meaning all your user data would be visible to any client using your application. You should **never** store sensitive data client-side.

Type this into your browser console, and you'll see what I mean.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].__vue__.$store.state
```

Vuex should be used for storing non-sensitive data of an individual user required to drive their session.

If you are storing all user data for the purpose of listing accounts so that they can be managed by an admin or something, then I would instead, make that API call on demand when you load whatever view you have which lists your user accounts. This way you will always have the most up-to-date data, without the need for constantly polling your API.

I would paginate that data, loading only the first 5 records (to keep the API call initially light), then provide your admins the ability to search for accounts; that searching should be done server side, through your API.

Example:

```js
methods: {
    fetchUsers(limit, page, search) {
        const thisIns = this;
        if (search) {
            this.userQuery = `/users/find?search=${search}`
        } else {
            this.userQuery = `/users/find?limit=${limit}&page=${page}`
        }
        thisIns.$http.get(this.userQuery)
            .then(async (response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
},
created() {
    this.fetchUsers(5, 1)
},
```

You can then call your `fetchUsers()` method as needed, such as when performing a search for user(s).

Since you are using Axios, you can also consider implementing a caching mechanism, [axios-cache-adapter](https://github.com/RasCarlito/axios-cache-adapter), so that your API calls are cached for some period of time you define. This would reduce the number of API calls hitting your server.

I also don't consider this to be scaleable. Remember that an application user will have to wait for this payload when they first load your app. This also has performance implications; as your user data grows over time, you'll be consuming more and more of the devices RAM.

Comment: thanks for your reply. This sounds a little bit messy to me. I would like to store everything or anything. I wouldn't like it to fetch some data every time and cache some data :/ Does Vuex have some storage limitations?

Comment: Vuex itself imposes no limits; the limits are with the clients browser and device, in terms of memory (ram) and local storage (disk). I do not consider it good practice to build your application in a manner that would directly impact a users device or application performance. I believe in maintaining a distinct separation from application and backend. An application should be nothing more than the interface to your data, by means of your APIs. This means you can create lightweight, performant applications that are easily changeable / migrate-able in the future. Just my two cents. Good luck!

Comment: if I got you correctly I would get into really troubles if I store user objects with profile images of some megabytes into the Vuex store?

Comment: then I should call the service functions directly and leave Vuex for this case ..

Comment: I just mean that I wouldn't store entire tables worth of data. It's perfectly okay to store the URL to the profile image for the logged in user, in Vuex. In my case, when I first authenticate a user (which is a call to one of my APIs), I return that users "identity" object. It contains whatever I need to drive that users session; things like their display name, the URL to their profile picture, and any application settings they may have chosen (ie: dark mode).

Comment: As a side note, I think it would be better to paginate when performing a search by keyword as well as it's a best practice.